# Hibernate reverse one to one undirectional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes `Cards` and `CardBalance`. In my DB sсhema table `card_balance` has foreign key on table `cards`. But in ORM I want that entity `Cards` has properties `CardBalance`, and entity `CardBalance` does't have propertie `Cards`.
I try do this in next way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARD_BALANCE")
public class CardBalance {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BALANCE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ", sequenceName = "CARD_BALANCE_SEQ")
    private Long balanceId;

    @Column(name="CARD_ID")
    private Long cardId;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
public class Cards implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CARDS_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CARDS_SEQ", sequenceName = "CARDS_SEQ")
    private Long cardId;

    @Column(name = "CARD_NAME", length = 30, unique = true)
    private String cardName;

    @Column(name="PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "CARD_KEY", nullable = false)
    private long cardKey;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private TypeCard typeCard;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CARD_ID", nullable = false)
    private CardBalance cardBalance;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CARD_ID")
    public Set<BalanceHist> balanceHists = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CARD_ID")
    public Set<Events> events = new HashSet<>();

}
```

but it does't work. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a mistake in your `@JoinColumn`, it should be:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BALANCE_ID", nullable = false)
private CardBalance cardBalance;
```